# bringing in data with knockout and the presenting it on the screen with correct tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

So I am loading in data in a file using KO and the displaying it on the screen

an example of the data

```js
'id': '5',
 'firstName': 'test',
 'lastName': 'person',
 'picture': 'images/05.jpg',
 'bio': 'Billy Bob Thornton, And The Mental-Institution Drama Girl, Interrupted, Which Earned Her An Oscar.\n\nSubsequently, Jolie Made A Series Of Blockbusters (Lara Croft: Tomb Raider) And Bombs (Sky Captain And The World Of Tomorrow)'
```

I am then loading in the data - all this works

```js
self.movieStar= ko.observableArray();
 var newData;
 
 ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function(item){

  var htmlstring = item.bio
  
  htmlstring = htmlstring.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "<br>");
  htmlDecode=  $('<div/>').html(htmlstring).text();

   newData = new MovieStar(item.id, item.firstName, item.lastName, item.picture, htmlDecode);
  self.movieStar.push(newData)
  
 });
```

and then displaying on page

```html
<aside class="mainRight" data-bind="foreach: movieStar">
        
        <div data-bind="attr: {id:'tab' +id}">
   <img data-bind="attr: {src:picture}" class="textWrap">
            <h3 data-bind="text: firstName + ' ' +  lastName"></h3>
            <p data-bind="text: bio"></p>
  </div>
```

All this is fine but its is ignoring the /n/n

this is why i added in this line

```js
htmlstring = htmlstring.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "<br>");
```

but then it just prints

```html
<br>
```

so I tried to Decode it using

```js
htmlDecode=  $('<div/>').html(htmlstring).text();
```

but then it just prints the

```html
<br>
```

again

how can I get around this so it actually has the spaces I need

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [html binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html) for `bio` (instead of `text` binding). I.e.

```
<p data-bind="html: bio"></p>
```